# ValueError: save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object

Tags: python, mysql, django

Hi I am recreating a website in django and this happens...
Django throw this error,

ValueError: save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'fk_deal'.

even though I have saved the foreign key related object. This is the view part.

```
if request.method == "POST":
    deal = DEAL()

    name = request.POST.get('name')

    revenue_2013 = request.POST.get('revenue_2013')

    if project_name:
        print project_name
        deal.name = project_name

    deal.save()

    print deal.id # prints None

    # financials 2013
    if revenue_2013:
         fin = DEALFINANCIALINFORMATION.objects.create(
                            financial_category_amount=revenue_2013,
                            financial_year='2013',
                            fk_deal = deal,
                            financial_category_id=1,
                            )
```

These are the models....

```
class DEAL(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=33L, db_column=u'COMPANY_NAME', blank=True)
    investmentrequired = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_deleted = MySQLBooleanField(db_column=u'IS_DELETED', blank=True, default=None)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=33L, db_column=u'NAME', blank=True)
    photo = models.CharField(max_length=66L, db_column=u'PHOTO', blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=85L, db_column=u'STATUS', blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True, db_column=u'TIMESTAMP', blank=True)
    teaser = models.TextField(db_column=u'TEASER', blank=True)
    currency_id = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, db_column=u'CURRENCY_ID', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(db_column=u'DESCRIPTION', blank=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey('COUNTRIES', null=True, db_column=u'COUNTRY_ID', blank=True)
    sector = models.ForeignKey('SECTORS', null=True, db_column=u'SECTOR_ID', blank=True)
    type = models.ForeignKey('TYPES', null=True, db_column=u'TYPE_ID', blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=85L, db_column=u'USERNAME', blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey('USER', null=True, db_column=u'USER_ID', blank=True)
    hitcounter = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, db_column=u'HITCOUNTER', blank=True)
    approx_usd = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, null=True, max_digits=19, db_column=u'approxUSD', blank=True)
    userdeal_id = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, db_column=u'USERDEAL_ID', blank=True)
    is_featuredeal = MySQLBooleanField(db_column=u'IS_FEATUREDEAL', blank=True, default=None)
    basic_company_email = models.CharField(max_length=33L, db_column=u'BASIC_COMPANY_EMAIL', blank=True)
    basic_company_name = models.CharField(max_length=33L, db_column=u'BASIC_COMPANY_NAME', blank=True)
    basic_company_phone = models.CharField(max_length=33L, db_column=u'BASIC_COMPANY_PHONE', blank=True)
    basic_company_website = models.CharField(max_length=33L, db_column=u'BASIC_COMPANY_WEBSITE', blank=True)
    basic_elevator_pitch = models.TextField(db_column=u'BASIC_ELEVATOR_PITCH', blank=True)
    basic_premoney_evaluation = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, null=True, max_digits=19, db_column=u'BASIC_PREMONEY_EVALUATION', blank=True)
    basic_question_1 = models.TextField(db_column=u'BASIC_QUESTION_1', blank=True)
    basic_question_2 = models.TextField(db_column=u'BASIC_QUESTION_2', blank=True)
    basic_question_3 = models.TextField(db_column=u'BASIC_QUESTION_3', blank=True)
    basic_summary = models.TextField(db_column=u'BASIC_SUMMARY', blank=True)
    basic_total_offering_amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, null=True, max_digits=19, db_column=u'BASIC_TOTAL_OFFERING_AMOUNT', blank=True)
    is_company = MySQLBooleanField(db_column=u'IS_COMPANY', blank=True, default=None)
    is_posted = MySQLBooleanField(db_column=u'IS_POSTED', blank=True, default=None)
    is_visible = MySQLBooleanField(db_column=u'IS_VISIBLE', blank=True, default=None)
    other_company_milestones = models.TextField(db_column=u'OTHER_COMPANY_MILESTONES', blank=True)
    projectname = models.CharField(max_length=33L, db_column=u'PROJECTNAME', blank=True)
    basicdealstage = models.ForeignKey('DEALSTAGES', null=True, db_column=u'BASICDEALSTAGE_ID', blank=True)
    basic_security_type = models.ForeignKey('SECURITYTYPES', null=True, db_column=u'BasicSecurityType_ID', blank=True)
    is_public = MySQLBooleanField(db_column=u'IS_PUBLIC', blank=True, default=None)
    profile_completed = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, db_column=u'PROFILE_COMPLETED', blank=True)
    is_closed = MySQLBooleanField(db_column=u'IS_CLOSED', blank=True, default=None)
    first_step_completed = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, db_column=u'FIRST_STEP_COMPLETED', blank=True, default=0L)
    second_step_completed = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, db_column=u'SECOND_STEP_COMPLETED', blank=True)
    third_step_completed = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, db_column=u'THIRD_STEP_COMPLETED', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'DEAL'

    def __unicode__(self):
        if self.name:
            return self.name
        else:
            return "No name"

class DEALFINANCIALINFORMATION(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    financial_category_amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, null=True, max_digits=19, db_column=u'FINANCIAL_CATEGORY_AMOUNT', blank=True)
    financial_year = models.CharField(max_length=33L, db_column=u'FINANCIAL_YEAR', blank=True)
    de_al_id = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, db_column=u'DEAl_ID', blank=True)
    financial_category_id = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, db_column=u'FINANCIAL_CATEGORY_ID', blank=True)
    fk_deal = models.ForeignKey('DEAL', null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'DEAL_FINANCIAL_INFORMATION'
```

The database was created from an existing MySQL database....
I send the data to the view using jquery POST....
I can't seem to find out what the problem is. Also even after saving the model if I print the id field it returns None instead....
Can somebody help me?

Comment: Does you database automatically assign the numbers for the id field? If the database were created by django this would happen, django therefor relies on the database to generate the ids.

Comment: Django doesn't know that your `BigIntegerField` primary key is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, so it won't look for a return value. It only sets the primary key value after a save when using an `AutoField`.